# Difference between `(&rest xs)` and `xs` in defmacro formal argument list

Tags: macros, pattern-matching, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

In Practical Common Lisp's [Chapter 8](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html), Macros: Defining Your Own, we define a macro `with-gensyms` as follows:

```
(defmacro with-gensyms ((&rest names) &body body)
  `(let ,(loop for n in names collect `(,n (gensym)))
    ,@body))
```

What is the purpose of the `(&rest names)`? If we replace it with just `names`, the effect seems to be the same. In both cases we pass in a list of symbols to be "gensym-ed".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference:

`(&rest names)` inside the arglist `((&rest names) &body body)` matches only lists. When somebody is using the macro with something else, the error comes from the macro expander:

> debugger invoked on a `SB-KERNEL::DEFMACRO-BOGUS-SUBLIST-ERROR`:
>
> error while parsing arguments to `DEFMACRO WITH-GENSYMS`:
>
> bogus sublist `A` to satisfy lambda-list `(&REST NAMES)`

`names` matches anything. When somebody is using the macro with not a list, then the error comes from the LOOP macro, which needs a list:

> debugger invoked on a `TYPE-ERROR`: The value `A` is not of type `LIST`.

Thus you get a better and earlier error.

Comment: So it's idiomatic to use `((&rest args))` when we expect `args` to be a list?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: wouldn't you want to use the more specific construct?